# Pass StreamWriter to another thread and close the thread after N seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have code like this:

```
StreamWriter successWriter = File.AppendText(pathSuccess);
task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    IEnumerable<string> lines = File
          .ReadLines(actualPath)
          .Skip(GetInt(positionNumericUpDown.Value));
    try
    {
        var options = new ParallelOptions()
        {
            CancellationToken = cts.Token,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = GetInt(maxThreadNumericUpDown.Text)
        };

        Parallel.ForEach<string>(lines, options, (line, loopState, idx) =>
        {
            options.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Result result = getResult(line);
            lock(successWriter)
            {
               successWriter.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", result.Url, result.Message);
               successWriter.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
},
TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Now I need every 60 seconds start another thread **NewThread** with method

```
 void checkForMoreResults(successWriter);
```

The **NewThread** can take more than 60 seconds so I need close the previosuly running thread before starting the new one (after every 60 seconds)

Any suggestion how can I do it will appreciated

Answer (score 0):

why not just use **BackgroundWorker** and call **CancelAsync**()?  it might be a little bit easier perhaps than the .net TPN APIs.